# Aligning symbols above a function

Tags: align, amsmath, overset

```
\begin{equation}
    \frac{IM(\overset{+}{Y},\overset{+}{\epsilon})}{\epsilon}
\end{equation}
```

So in my equation, I've noticed that the '+' above 'Y' and 'epsilon' are not aligned when I use \overset. Is there any fix to this?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, a poor workaround would be to naïvely use the `overset{}` function over both the 'Y' and 'epsilon' (as I cannot think of a better way!), for example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation} 
        \frac{IM(\overset{\,+\,\,+}{Y, \epsilon})}{\epsilon}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The spacing is hard-coded which is unfortunate, but it may be OK for your needs.

Comment: Understand it's hard-coded, but works perfectly! Don't really use this function that much anyway.

Comment: You also might ise

Answer (score 2):

I would propose to do that with the `accents` package and a `\vphantom`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accents}
\newcommand\plus[1]{\accentset{+}{#1}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
        \frac{IM(\plus{Y}, \plus{\vphantom{Y}\epsilon})}{\epsilon}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a smaller `+` sign. Here I provide a command that raises the `+` if desired, by using `\pv*`: this may not always be wanted.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed for LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\pv}{sm}{%
  \overset{\scriptscriptstyle+}{\IfBooleanT{#1}{\vphantom{T}}#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\frac{IM(\pv{Y},\pv*{\epsilon})}{\epsilon}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\pv{\epsilon}+\epsilon
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]